# XQuery - How to check float number has more than 6 digits after decimal point?

Tags: floating-point, xquery

I have a number like `1.123456789`

How can I check if this number has more than 6 digits after the `.` in XQuery?

Comment: Do you have that value in XQuery as a number? Of which type exactly? Or in some untyped XML?

Comment: i received this number from file as a float and i want to make check if has more than 6 digit to ignore it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could cast as a string and count the precision digits:

```
1.123456789 => string() => substring-after(".") => string-length() gt 6
```

If you are looking to control the precision, you could use functions such as [`round-half-to-even()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-round-half-to-even) to ensure that your number is not greater than 6 digits of precision:

```
round-half-to-even(1.123456789, 6)
```

and if your XQuery engine supports 3.1, [`round()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-round) now has an optional precision parameter:

```
round(1.123456789, 6)
```